# what would be stopping my html page from displaying in compute-engine vm upon using "npm start"

Tags: node.js, npm, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, firewall

I am new and hopefully there is a simple answer to my error.
I have installed node.js and npm in a compute-engine vm. I am using the ssh on the vm to access my files. I've created a basic html page (I am doing this part of a course). And I am now to serve that page by command npm start. When I start that, everything seems to be working, but when I click the external ip link to view the html page, it just times out. I have tried opening firewalls but maybe am opening the incorrect ones. I would appreciate some advice on what to try next to fix this. Thanks

Here is what I see:

```
        > gitstore@1.0.0 start /home/barklera/gitstore
        > npm run lite
        > gitstore@1.0.0 lite /home/barklera/gitstore
        > lite-server
        Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
        ** browser-sync config **
        {
          injectChanges: false,
          files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
          watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
          server: {
            baseDir: './',
            middleware: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ]
          }
        }
        [Browsersync] Access URLs:
         -----------------------------------
            Local: http://localhost:3004
            External: http://<my ip>:3004
         -----------------------------------
            UI: http://localhost:3005
            UI External: http://localhost:3005
         -----------------------------------
        [Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
        [Browsersync] Watching files...
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to create a firewall rule to allow ingress traffic on the ports 3004 & 3005** (at least I see them in the snippet). [By default they are blocked](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules).

You can use [console ui](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/add) or `gcloud` command to do that:

`gcloud compute --project=proj_name firewall-rules create myrule1 --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:3004,tcp:3005 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=tag1`

Also to make this rule work you have to [assign "tag1" network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to your instance.

**Also - make sure internal firewall in your VM doesn't block that traffic - it shouldn't but better double check it:**

`netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

and you will get something similar:

```
wbogacz_google_com@ssh3-osl-enabled:~/.ssh$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1762585940 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:24224         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:514           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

You can clearly ports the machine is listening on - there should be 3004/3005 ports there.